# OpenCV 3 VideoWriter Inserting an Extra Frames

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to write a video in OpenCV3 (Python 3.6). I found this code posted somewhere. The code works but when I play the video, it seems that every few seconds seconds or so it inserts the wrong frame. It looks like it's the first frame of the sequence. Here is how the video looks. ([Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3HKaQlzS8Y) in case the embed code doesn't run)

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J3HKaQlzS8Y" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is the code i'm using on my Windows 10 (64bit)
    #!/usr/local/bin/python3

```
import cv2
import argparse
import os

# Construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-ext", "--extension", required=False, default='jpg', 
help="extension name. default is 'jpg'.")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=False, default='output.mp4', 
help="output video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# Arguments
dir_path = '.'
ext = args['extension']
output = args['output']

images = []
for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if f.endswith(ext):
        images.append(f)

# Determine the width and height from the first image
image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, images[0])
frame = cv2.imread(image_path)
cv2.imshow('video',frame)
height, width, channels = frame.shape

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v') # Be sure to use lower case
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))

for image in images:

    image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, image)
    frame = cv2.imread(image_path)

    out.write(frame) # Write out frame to video

    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'): # Hit `q` to exit
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print("The output video is {}".format(output))
```

Any pointers would be apprecited

Answer (score 0):

In your code, after this code:

```
images = []
for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
if f.endswith(ext):
    images.append(f)
```

just add:

```
 images = sorted(images, key=lambda x: (int(re.sub('\D','',x)),x))
```

so that we will get a sorted data. Hence the video frames will be all set in there positions. Don't forget to `import re` as header file.